# Segmentation fault 11 with heap class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have this code, it is just class for heap. Now tried to convert dynamic array to class heap and then print it out, i used pointers for that, because it isn't allowed

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class heap
{
public:
    heap(int size);
    ~heap();
    int add_element(int element);
    int get_min();
    void arr_to_q(int *arr, int len);
    void show();
    /* data */

private:
    void down(int i, int len);
    int* Buffer;
    int mysize;
    int currentsize;
    void up(int i, int len);
    void reallocate();
};

heap::heap(int size){
    int* Buffer=new int[size];
    currentsize=size;
    mysize=size;
    cout<<mysize;

}
heap::~heap(){

}

void heap::arr_to_q(int *arr, int len){
    cout<<currentsize;
    currentsize+=len;
    if (len>mysize){
        reallocate();
    }
    for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--){
        up(i, len);
    }
}

void heap::reallocate(){
    int *sbuffer=Buffer;
    int *Buffer = new int[mysize*2];
    mysize*=2;
    for (int i=0; i<mysize; i++){
        Buffer[i]=sbuffer[i];

    }
    delete [] sbuffer;
}


void heap::up(int i, int len){
    int par, sosed, min;
    if (i%2==0){
        par=i/2-1;
        sosed=i-1;
    }
    else{
        par=i/2;
        sosed=sosed+1;
    }
    if (Buffer[i]<Buffer[sosed]){
        min=i;
    }
    else{
        min=sosed;
    }
    if (Buffer[min]<Buffer[par]){
        int c = Buffer[min];
        Buffer[min]=Buffer[par];
        Buffer[par]=c;
        up(min, len);
    }
}

void heap::show(){
    for(int i=0; i<currentsize; i++){
        cout<<"You queue is"<<Buffer[i];
    // cout<<"currentsize: "<<currentsize;
    }
}

int main(){
    int len;
    printf("Vvedite dlinu massiva");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    int *arr=new int[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len;i++){
        printf("Vvedite %d element\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    heap heaps(5);
    heaps.arr_to_q(arr, len);
    // heaps.show();
    delete [] arr;
```

But after lauching it crashes with error of sigmentation fault 11. Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried to debug already? That's loads of code you want us to inspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (first?) problem is in your constructor

```
heap::heap(int size){
    int* Buffer=new int[size];
    ....
```

declares a local variable `Buffer`, allocates memory for this then leaks it when the function completes.  The member variable `Buffer` is never initialised so will probably cause a segfault when it is first accessed.

The fix is simply to initialise the member variable instead

```
heap::heap(int size){
    Buffer=new int[size];
    ....
```

Note that there are also problems in `reallocate`.  The class member `Buffer` is freed but not pointed towards the locally allocated `Buffer`.  You also read beyond the end of the old buffer while copying old content over.  Accessing memory you don't own invokes undefined behaviour and could be another cause of segfaults.

Something like the following should fix these problems:

```
void heap::reallocate(){
    int newSize = mysize*2;
    int *newBuffer = new int[newSize];
    for (int i=0; i<mysize; i++){
        newBuffer[i] = Buffer[i];
    }
    mysize = newSize
    delete [] Buffer;
    Buffer = newBuffer;
}
```